# VBA(EXCEL) extract information from different rows with various criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file which contain information of the composite in 1 row and in below rows  information of the components of this composite. Number of component rows below a composite are varied between 2 - 20 and there can be many composites in a file.

[image: File example i deal with]

My question is: is it possible somehow to define how many rows are in the components  and to extract information from each component in to one cell(concatenate). Problem I face is that number of rows are different each time and there can be multiple composites in the file containing components. So i do not know how to stop my loop and start a new composite aggregation.

Maybe there are ways to loop from Request1(ColumnA) and assign "Request1" as a text to every empty column below until it reaches Request2, after that is finished to concatenate based on Request"n"

Example what i want the data to look like

[image: Outcome]

~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I might have over complicated my question

I was just looking to concatenate information from different set of rows(for simplicity just 1 consistent cell from every row) in to 1 cell(for example last cell in the first column) for each specific composite(which contains components)  My problem is I do not know how to stop the concatenation and start a new one when i am working with a new composite(new set of rows).

So as an example from the first picture, I would like to have "Request 1 Green Yellow White" (cells: A1, F1, F2,F3) populated in cell J1, and "Request 2 Amber Red White Blue" (cells: A4,F4,F5,F6,F7)populated i cell J4

#######EDIT

I have established another way of doing but still struggle with concatenation formula.
In this picture example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQdNu.jpg

If my table stars from row 2

=IF(A2="",J1,A2)  - by putting this in column J and dragging down i will get his Request 1
Request 1
Request 1
Request 2
Request 2
Request 2
Request 2

Then  deleting duplicates  i will be left only with 
Request 1
Request 2
Then I  can concatenate columns i want going by Request 1 or request 2 criteria(index match), but I cant figure out how to do it...

Comment: Some of us can't see photos.   It appears that you have category names in one row and members of that category in the rows directly beneath.  Sometimes you may need add member rows beneath a certain category, which changes the row numbers of all category names below that one.  And you want to know how to keep track of category names, which row they are in, and which is their members last row.  Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please advise if you still have problems looking at provided images? How my template looks - https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQdNu.jpg , how the end result should look https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf5eJ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use array formula to work out the start and end rows, like `=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$20<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$20)),ROW())` to find the next populated cell in A1:A20, where this would be in the cell G1.  So in G1, I have a fixed 1, then in G2 down, I have =H1+1, then in each H filled down I have `=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$20<>"",ROW($A$2:$A$20)),ROW())`  this gives the following

[image]

Unfortunately we cant do the concat using what we have in Excel, so this will help with your loop start and ends.  Number of products, is the difference in the 2

Comment: Thanks, I get #value when pasting in to column H. but its a good logical start.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, then the following code may help.  You want to be able to add element rows beneath categories rows, and when you do that it changes the row number for every row beneath the new row.  This code will show you that it doesn't matter which row the category is on because you can find it's row number any time, and also the number of elements beneath it.

The trick is to add a word in col A of each category that will not be found in any element A value.  For example, A1 might read "Category: Apples"," and there may be ten element rows under "Category: Apples"  And then under those rows another category in col A will be "Category: Bananas."  The code below looks for the value "Category:" in col A and gets the row number of each category line and how many elements are under it.  With a little math you can figure out where to insert a new line for a new element row or what row to concatenate.  And you won't need to hard code the rows numbers of the category.  Just run this simple code and it will give you those row numbers to get and concatenate all rows beneath any category.

```
Sub findCategoryRows()
Dim lastRowColA As Long, myArray() As Variant
Dim rowOfCategoryNameArray, nameOfCategoryNameArray, categoryCounter As Long


    lastRowColA = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    myArray = Range("A1:A" & lastRowColA)

    categoryCounter = 1
    ReDim rowOfCategoryNameArray(1 To 1)
    ReDim nameOfCategoryNameArray(1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        If InStr(1, Range("A" & i).Value, "Category: ") Then
            rowOfCategoryNameArray(categoryCounter) = i
            nameOfCategoryNameArray(categoryCounter) = Range("A" & i).Value
            categoryCounter = categoryCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve rowOfCategoryNameArray(1 To categoryCounter)
            ReDim Preserve nameOfCategoryNameArray(1 To categoryCounter)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To UBound(rowOfCategoryNameArray) - 1
        If i <> UBound(rowOfCategoryNameArray) - 1 Then
            Debug.Print nameOfCategoryNameArray(i) & " has " & (rowOfCategoryNameArray(i + 1) - rowOfCategoryNameArray(i)) - 1 & " element rows under it."
        Else
             Debug.Print nameOfCategoryNameArray(i) & " has " & (lastRowColA - rowOfCategoryNameArray(i)) & " element rows under it."
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John, Can you please provide an illustration of what the data should look like where the code is looking to as I am struggling to get any results of it. In terms of my question, I was just looking to concatenate information from different set of rows(for simplicity just 1 consistent cell from every row) in to 1 cell(for example last cell in the first column) for each specific composite(which contains components) . I would use a separate sheet for my table structure but  my problem is I do not know how to stop the concatenation and start a new one when i am working with a new composite.

Comment: I have edited my question at the bottom, it should be more simple and clear. Really appreciate the effort.

Comment: Yes, I think that I totally misunderstood your question.  Can you define some words for me?  Concatenate from different set of rows?  Do you want to take one cell from each of several rows and concatenate them into another cell?   What is a composite?  Is a composite an already concatenated string?  What are components?  Are those the elements of a concatenated string?

Comment: Yes i want to take one cell from each of several rows matching a specific criteria(components) and concatenate them in to one cell(for each individual composite). Composite in my opinion is a main group(level information) containing information underneath(components/sleeves). In the first Picture above i would define Request 1 and Request 2(column A) as a composite, and information in range (E1:I3) are components for Request 1 and range(E4:I7) components of the Request 2. Apologies for confusion, was not sure how else to define it, group(composite) and port groups(components) :)

Comment: As an example from the first picture, I would like to have "Request 1 Green Yellow White" (cells: A1, F1, F2,F3) populated in cell J1, and "Request 2 Amber Red White Blue" (cells: A4,F4,F5,F6,F7)populated i cell J4. Knowing the logic how to concatenate information for each set of groups and stop when the new group starts  is what i am looking for